Running an OpenRewrite recipe with Gradle never completes
I'm trying out OpenRewrite and I wanted to test it out with the "Remove unused imports" recipe against our a large multi-module Gradle project.
I'm opting for the init-script approach so I don't have to edit our build.gradle. I copied the script from the website and named it unused-imports.gradle.
I added an exclusion section for excluding our generated files:
initscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2" }
    }
    dependencies { classpath("org.openrewrite:plugin:latest.release") }
}
rootProject {
    plugins.apply(org.openrewrite.gradle.RewritePlugin)
    dependencies {
        rewrite("org.openrewrite:rewrite-java")
    }
    rewrite {
        activeRecipe("org.openrewrite.java.RemoveUnusedImports")
        exportDatatables = true

        exclusion(
            "**/generated/**"
        )
    }
    afterEvaluate {
        if (repositories.isEmpty()) {
            repositories {
                mavenCentral()
            }
        }
    }
}

When I run it with the command wsl ./gradlew --init-script unused-imports.gradle rewriteDryRun it seems to be going alright. I see all our modules en sub-modules being parsed until, after about half an hour I'm seeing this:
Scanning sources in project :
Using active styles [org.openrewrite.java.Checkstyle]
<============-> 99% EXECUTING [58m 45s]
> IDLE                                                                                                                                                                             
> IDLE
> :rewriteDryRun
> IDLE

After an hour I terminated the command because there seemed to be no progress.
What might be wrong?
Additional info:

I had to tweak the Gradle properties with these values as at first it ran out of heap space : org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx25G -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:GCLockerRetryAllocationCount=100. (taken from another StackOverflow thread)
I'm also getting a lot of these kinds of errors:

Cause 80: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find some:dependency:.
Required by:
    project :our:module > project :another:module

I tried modifying the repositories section so it mirrors our build.gradle one but it didn't make a difference:
afterEvaluate {
        if (repositories.isEmpty()) {
            repositories {
                maven {
                    url = uri('https://our/artifactory/repo')
                }
                mavenCentral()
            }
        }
    }


Ok, at the end of my work day I let it run and eventually it actually completed!
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 6h 7m 51s

It seems I just had to be very patient.
